# Docker-Container Console Encoding in IntelliJ

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, encoding, character-encoding, console

my Problem is the follows:

I'm trying to achive, that the Console ion IntelliJ for Docker-Container uses the Right Encoding. Right now it looks as follows:
[image: INtelliJ Output]

While in Docker itself it looks like this:
[image: Docker Output]

If i run a simple main in IntelliJ the Output is follows:
[image: main in IntelliJ]

i changed every Option i found in IntelliJ to UTF-8, still nothing changed. Its just weird, that it does work in Docker and normal console, just not the Docker-Console in IntelliJ.
Dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM fabric8/java-alpine-openjdk11-jre:latest

ENV JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
ENV AB_ENABLED=jmx_exporter
#ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = "-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"

# Be prepared for running in OpenShift too
RUN adduser -G root --no-create-home --disabled-password 1001 \
  && chown -R 1001 /deployments \
  && chmod -R "g+rwX" /deployments \
  && chown -R 1001:root /deployments

COPY target/lib/* /deployments/lib/
COPY target/*-runner.jar /deployments/app.jar
EXPOSE 8080

# run with user 1001
USER 1001

ENTRYPOINT [ "/deployments/run-java.sh" ]
```

The commented out Line was one of my Attempts of fixing it, also adding the Option to the JAVA_OPTIONS. Didnt help (even without the Options added "file.encoding" returns UTF-8). And since it works perfectly in Docker, i dont think the Problem is in the File.

What else can i try?

Comment: You need to configure for base image. Mostly it is `ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: That doesnt help, still same Error. But i still think its aProblem in IntelliJ since it works fine in the Docker console

Answer (score 5):

IntelliJ IDEA -> Help -> Edit Custom VM Options
and add line:
`-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Comment: that fixed it for me in WebStorm